# A simple java httpserver. Changing the value of an input field on the client side

Tags: java, html

I am trying to create a simple Java HTTP server. It loads a index.html file and then sends it to the client. The index.html contains the layout of a calculator. If the client then presses on of the buttons I can easily get a response from the server. I would then like to update the value of the display field on the client side. How would I go about doing this?

The HTTP server

```
try{
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(port), 0);
        server.createContext("/calc", new MyHandler());
        server.createContext("/equals", new equalsHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
        server.start();
        //while(true){
            //Socket socket = server.accept();
            //ServiceThread serviceThread = new ServiceThread(socket);
            //serviceThreads.add(serviceThread);
        //}
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

Here is the handler.

```
public class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
        //Loading the file to send to the client
        fileScanner = new Scanner(path);
        String response = "";
        while(fileScanner.hasNext()){
            response = response + fileScanner.nextLine();
            //print("Line");
        }

        print("Client has requested the page");

        Headers h = t.getResponseHeaders();
        h.set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");

        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
}
```

And the html file. I want to update the value of the input field.

```
<style>
a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none; /* no underline */
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
*
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 2px;
}
.button
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.display
{
    width: 210px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: lightGrey;
}
</style>
<table>
  <tr colspan="4" >
    <input type="number" class="display" value ="0"></input><br>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class = "button"><a href="1">1</a></button></td>
    <td><button class = "button"><a href="2">2</a></button></td> 
    <td><button class = "button"><a href="3">3</a></button></td>
    <td><button class = "button"><a href="divide">/</a></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class = "button"><a href="4">4</a></button></td>
    <td><button class = "button"><a href="5">5</a></button></td> 
    <td><button class = "button"><a href="6">6</a></button></td>
    <td><button class = "button"><a href="multiply">*</a></button>             </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class = "button"><a href="7">7</a></button></td>
    <td><button class = "button"><a href="8">8</a></button></td> 
    <td><button class = "button"><a href="9">9</a></button></td>
    <td><button class = "button"><a href="minus">-</a></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class = "button"><a href="point">.</a></button></td>
    <td><button class = "button"><a href="0">0</a></button></td> 
    <td><button class = "button"><a href="equals">=</a></button></td>
    <td><button class = "button"><a href="plus">+</a></button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The only thing relevant here is the .html file, unless it isn't beign delivered properly.

Comment: If i understood you correct is AJAX what you are looking for http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp